# Sequelize: camelCase attribute names in but snake_case in posrgres?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  someAttribute: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true },
}, {
  'freezeTableName': true
});
```

This is an existing database where the column names are named with snake case `some_attribute`. However, since it is a nodejs code base, I would like to use camelCase `someAttribute`.

Is this possible with sequelize?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is a bit old, just posting this answer for future googlers.

You can override the column name using the `field` attribute.

http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {
 // You can specify a custom field name via the "field" attribute:
 fieldWithUnderscores: { type: Sequelize.STRING, field: "field_with_underscores" }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only chance you got is to override the getters/setter in the model:

```
var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  some_attribute: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true },
},
// getters and setters
getterMethods: {
  someAttribute: function(){return this.getDataValue("some_attribute");}
},
setterMethods: {
  someAttribute: function(v){this.setDataValue("some_attribute", v);}
},
{
  'freezeTableName': true
});
```